# Detecting if monitor is on/off

Tags: display, monitors

I want to detect if my monitor is on/off. This is because I need to record my screen time as an assignment. Numerous google searches haven't helped, as they return answers saying that it's not possible, or answers that only work on Windows, and answers that do not apply to my DELL monitor.

I tried to use `xrandr` but that didn't help either as it doesn't return information about the current state of the monitor.

Comment: Does `xrandr ` really not return anything suitable? I find that `xrandr | grep -q " connected " && echo "monitor connected"` or `xrandr | grep -q " connected " || echo "monitor not connected"` works.

Comment: @Bib Tried and doesn't work. Turning off the monitor or unplugging doesn't change the output.

Comment: Then what is the output? Who is logged in? How are you running the command? Don't dripfeed info.

Comment: Are you running your monitor through a HDMI interface?

Comment: @Seamus Yes, I am running the monitor through a HDMI interface.

Comment: @Bib `xrandr | grep -q " connected " && echo "monitor connected` always outputs `moniter connected`, and `xrandr | grep -q " connected " || echo "monitor not connected"` never outputs anything.

Comment: Since you're using HDMI (with presumably a Linux computer), the CEC (Consumer Electronics Control) software may provide a solution for your application. There is [kernel support](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/media/cec.html) for CEC, and there is a [`libcec` library](https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/blob/master/docs/README.linux.md). There's much more info available for searching [1](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cec-utils+hdmi-cec&t=ffab&ia=web), [2](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=linux+hdmi-cec+software&ia=web). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

check online about `DPMS`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_Power_Management_Signaling

perhaps `xset -q` it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting. I've added `DPMS` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/dpms.conf` following the arch documentation, however `xset -q` still returns `Server does not have the DPMS extension`. Am I doing something wrong?